# Event on hovering over an option in a lightning:combobox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-combobox

Is it possible to register an event on an option hovering in `lightning:combobox`?

The best resource about the `lightning:combobox` I was able to find is [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:combobox/example).

It tells me nothing about the event I would like to register. Also, I know that in the ordinary html `select` it is impossible to register this kind of event. So, I am assuming it is not possible to register the event in lightning as well.

Just in order to be completely sure I am asking about it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This even is not supported by this component. I would write my own combobox and then it should be no problem to register such event.